# Retrieve my app Service so that i can stop it

Tags: android, service, background, preference

In my android app i already have created a service which is getting data on a background thread and sending it to the server regularly. I have three category of users which has been set by preference Activity, Now i want that My service should only run if and only if a particular type of user had been chosen, else service should get stop. So i want to stop the service on the change of my sharedpreference (listpreference in the xml file). How can i retrieve the reference of my service (which is running in the background not a new reference) and bind to stop when user change the value in listpreference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind to it in order to stop it. Wherever you have a `Context` reference (`Activity`, `Service` or base application context) just call [`stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29):

```
private void stopServiceUsingContext(Context context) {
    context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyServiceClass.class));
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to stop the service in response to a preference change listener, then you should have a reference to an `Activity` which extends `Context` so above code applies

Comment: sorry by mistake i have written to your answer actually i am new to stackoverflow.